# Android: How do name the layout folder

Tags: android, layout, directory

How do i name a layout folder which for only between android 4.0 to 4.3?

I know how to do it for one version but not sure in between

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The API level supported by the device. For example, v1 for API level 1
>   (devices with Android 1.0 or higher) and v4 for API level 4 (devices
>   with Android 1.6 or higher). See the Android API levels document for
>   more information about these values.

So, you need just create directory for Android 4.0 (v14), and other for API 4.4 (v19). All you v14 resources will be used for v14-v18.